# Redirect::away(...) equivalent for Lumen?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I'm attempting to port a portion of a Laravel 4 app to Lumen, but I'm unable to figure out the equivalent of Laravel 4's `Redirect::away(...);` function for Lumen.

I've tried keeping it the same which doesn't work. I've also tried `return redirect()->away($location);` as suggested in a similar question I found, but that also fails with the error `Call to undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Http\Redirector::away()`.

I feel like the answer to this is really simple, but unfortunately it's not documented anywhere and I can't figure out the right combination of things to get it to work.

My fallback is to use `header('Location : '.$location);` but would prefer to avoid it if there's a built in way to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be fine to do `return redirect($location)` in most cases.

See https://medium.com/@zwacky/laravel-redirect-to-vs-redirect-away-dd875579951f for the minor differences (it'll `trim()` your URL and check that it's valid).